# How to access all the datafields of a class?

Tags: java, reflection

I have some classes like Client, Employee, Property
I am maintaining the list of all the objects as array lists in a class names NIC.
So Java code for class NIC is like:

```
    class NIC
{
  static ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
  static ArrayList<Property> propertyList = new ArrayList<Property>();
  static ArrayList<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<Client>();

 //rest of the code
  public static void backItUp()
  {
    //this method reads all the objects data from array lists and stores it in a file
  }
}
```

I am stuck on the method backItUp() which is supposed to read all the objects data from array list and store it in a file.

I don't know if there is any method which can access all the data fields of current class or at least returns a reference of each data field.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user717417: In `backItUp`, why can't you simply refer to the fields by their names?

Comment: @user717417 You might want to specify what language you're talking about here. At the very least, put the language in the tags. You can edit your question to add extra information.

Comment: @aix: I want to generalize the code so that I need not to update the method 'backItUp()' everytime I update the fields of class NIC or even after chenging the name of class NIC

Comment: That kind of generalization goes too far. While you can find out the mebers of a class using reflectin, you must at least tell the name of the class.

Comment: @lngo: As the method backItUp resides in the same class, finding the name of the class will not be much tedious. The real problem is how to access all the objects stored in the array lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to remove the `static` modifiers from all your fields and methods, and make `NIC` a proper object that can be instantiated. When you adhere to OOP (Object Oriented Principles), you'll find everything becomes easier.  After that, all you need to do is make `NIC` implement `Serializable`.  The default serialization routine will automatically save everything in your class that is not marked as `transient`.  `ArrayList`s and all other JDK collections are already serializable, so no further work is required.  Just read the guide that KDM posted.

However, if you decide to add more fields or methods later, you will still end up with compatibility problems since old persisted objects will no longer match the signature of the new, updated class.  This is a consideration all programmers must make.  Using `serialVersionUID` can help a little, for instance, in cases where you're just adding new methods but no new fields, but proper testing is needed to ensure backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good case for serialization to me. Have a look at http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/ or may be a bit of googling does help.

Comment: As the link explains, I can backup the objects through serialization if I explicitly pass the name of the object.
But here I am more interested in backing up the data of fields of the class without needing to refer any name. So that in future, if I need to add or remove array lists or change the name of class, I need not to change the code of the method 'backItUp()'

Comment: Except in special cases, you don't need to refer to individual fields while serializing. May be I am not clear about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Class members are accessed with Classname.membername. You don't nedd an extra method for that.

Comment: Method backItUp() and all the array lists are static. So there will not be any instance of class NIC.

Comment: Indeed! So where is the problem that user####### has?

Comment: Here I am interested in backing up the data of fields of the class without needing to refer any name. So that in future, if I need to add or remove array lists or change the name of class, I need not to change the code of the method 'backItUp()'. I want to make it more generalized.

Comment: You might want to look at the DWIM method, perhaps. :)

Comment: DWIM method? I don't know what is it. And google also doesn't give any clue. Will you please elaborate or suggest some link?

Comment: Can't there be any feasible solution possible for the issue?